# possible solutions for the given equation

Tags: algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Given X,p,a,b. We need to find out how many positive integers n ( 1 <= n <= X) satisfies the following condition:-

```
na^n ≡ b(mod p)

Constraints:  
2 <= p <= 10^6,  
1 <= a,b< p,  
1 <= X <= 10^12
```

I have no idea how to solve this question, any approach or proof will be highly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming in its current form.  Can you specify what you need please, in a way that makes it programming-related? Right now it seems to be better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Do you mean 10^6 and 10^12 instead of 106 and 1012? As written, the numbers are very small.

Comment: @Lomtrur I think it's a programming problem. As far as I know, there's no direct mathematical solution, so it's problem of finding an efficient method of computation. Computational maths problems are not purely programming and not purely mathematical, and I think such questions could go here or on math.stackexhange. WIthout solving them, it's hard to know whether question is more mathematical or computational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes `p` is prime.

For each `i` from 1 upwards, compute `a^i`. At some point (call it `q`), you'll get to 1 and then you can stop. Then finding all `n <= X` such that `na^n = b (mod p)` and `a^n = a^i (mod p)` is a question of counting all solutions to `n = b*(a^i)^-1 (mod p)` and `n=i (mod q)`, which you can do using the Chinese remainder theorem.

This process enumerates all solutions exactly once, and if you're careful runs in O(p) time. (The care is needed to avoid O(p log p) if you calculate `a^i (mod p)` and `(a^i)^-1 (mod p)` from scratch each iteration).

Comment: Just some notes: This is only right if you assume `p` is a prime number and `a` is not `1` or `0` mod `p`. The question looks like `p` is meant to be prime, but it is not written there.

Comment: Unfortunately the claim that *a^i takes on every value from 1 to p-1 exactly once* is only true if a is a primitive root mod p. Not every a will be a primitive root.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk you're right, but it's easily fixable. I edited the answer.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Yep, every element has an order (q) which divides p-1.